# What is the mechanism of ring contraction of 6-bromo-7-methoxy-2,3,4,7-tetrahydrooxepine from seven to five?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have recently come across a paper from [here](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2011/cc/c0cc02244f#!divAbstract).I have tried to workout the mechanism for the following reaction presented in the paper.

[image]

I was able to workout mechanism till acetal formation.It is a ring expansion from six to seven. However,the next step is a ring reduction from seven to five upon heating.

Can someone please explain what is actually happening during ring reduction, and why it happens?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in scheme 3 of the paper you cited! The 7-membered acetal undergoes ring-opening to the α,β-unsaturated oxocarbenium ion, then conjugate addition to give the 5-membered tetrahydrofuran. A bit of arrow pushing and addition of solvent gives the other THF product

Not sure the legality of posting screenshots of papers, so I redrew the scheme:

[image]

Comment: @ PCK I hit a pay wall and could not open this paper.

Comment: @ PCK it is obvious, after protonation ,C-O bond breaks,followed by 1,4 addition, just great.